# Remove 3m along a line

Tags: qgis, line

I have multiple bufferstops on railways. I want to cut out 3m (1,5 m in each direction along the rails) of the railway lines with the buffer stop in the middle. Buffering does not work here because, I do not want to touch lines next to each other.
The railway lines may have more than up bufferstop. It is not certain if the bufferstops are exactly on the lines. some bufferstops are not even on the desired railways in red.
I checked with  select by expression and `overlay disjoint` if the points are really on the lines. Does not look like it (for the yellow ones). I am using OSM data.
How can I do this (something like buffer along a line)?

[image]
[image]

with the suggested solution below, QGIS is working but not returing the correct lines.

My project and the geopackage with the bufferstops and the rails:
[Railwayproject](https://zenodo.org/record/7040410#.YxB9SxzP3IU)

I used:
[image]

result:

-Solved-
It is important not to use the suggestionbox in "geometry by expression" but the same name as in the layer. So using the suggestion box does not work for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I stronlgy doubt the tracks are closer than 1.5 m to each other. So feel free to buffer and use difference.

Comment: true but I want to do this for other larger objects (switches, crossings) too.

Comment: What means does "not returing the correct lines"? Can you show the result? Otherwise it's difficult to help. You also did not mention you have more than one points on each line. This expression works for one point per line. Please provide more information in your question about your exact setting. Otherwise, the answer will not fit your exact use case.

Comment: I am not sure but I think OSM data is good enough to put one bufferstop at one line.

Comment: OK: can you describe the problem you have? What is the output if you try it this way? The question is not if "data is good enough" for one bufferstop per line - the question is: what to actually have? I guess best would be if you could share your data + project for testing.

Comment: In your last screenshot, you have large black dots (bufferstops) that cover the line. If you remove the dots: doesn't the 1.5 meter gap in the lines layer appear? I guess your points cover the result. 1.5 m is a small distance at this scale - smaller than the shop icons or the size of your points... So there are gaps, but you don't see them.

Comment: I tried again with just one line and one buffer. But it returns just the line itself. there are no gaps in between. same outcome with the whole layer. there are not the wanted gaps in between

Comment: Can you share Project + data?

Comment: I tried the solution with the data+project you provided and it works fine. Are you sure you made adaptaption of point layer accordingly? Line 5 must be: `overlay_nearest ('bufferstops', $geometry, limit:=1)[0]`. See second screenshot in my updated answer. Check if it works the same for you.

Comment: Be sure to really zoom in and disable visibility of the point layer: the 1.5m gap is really small; see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9WUW.png

Comment: It finally works. Code is correct but it does not work if I look up the layer in the suggestion box. It needs to be the name used in the layer box. Instead of 'bufferstop[...]' it needs to be just 'bufferstop'. see above.

Comment: I guess the "suggestionbox" (as you name it) does not work because you have the layer name inclosed in two single quotes (as I can see on your screenshot): `overlay_nearest (''bufferstop_e5c.....''`. It should be only **one single quote**: `overlay_nearest ('bufferstop_e5c.....'` - like this, it should work with the simple layer name of the "suggestionbox" as well. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olQOw.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use QGIS expression with Geometry generator or Geometry by expression. Use this expression on the railway line layer and replace `point` (line 5) with the name of your point (bufferstop) layer:

```
with_variable(
    'stop',
    line_locate_point ( 
        $geometry, 
        overlay_nearest ('point', $geometry, limit:=1)[0]
    ),
    difference (
        $geometry,
        buffer (
            line_substring (
                $geometry, 
                @stop-1.5,
                @stop+1.5
            ),0.1
        )
    )
)
```

*The red line is created based on the black line, but cutting out a distance to both sides of the point:*
[image]

[image]

Comment: synatax seems correct  but returns not the wanted geometry. for `point` I insert the bufferstop and apply this to my railway layer? "your line layer" confuses me a bit. the bufferstop are not lines?!

Comment: Sorry, I meant point layer, see updated answer. Does it work? If not, can you provide more details, screenshot etc.? Otherwise it's difficult to see what goes wrong.